# Get stdout of a shell command using boost process

Tags: c++, boost, boost-process

I am trying to implement a function in C++ that runs a shell command and returns the exit code, `stdout` and `stderr.` I am using the `Boost process library`

```
std::vector<std::string> read_outline(std::string & file)
{
    bp::ipstream is; //reading pipe-stream
    bp::child c(bp::search_path("nm"), file, bp::std_out > is);

    std::vector<std::string> data;
    std::string line;

    while (c.running() && std::getline(is, line) && !line.empty())
        data.push_back(line);

    c.wait();

    return data;
}
```

In the above [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.io) from boost's website, in the while loop the condition c.running() is checked. What if the process finishes executing before the while loop is reached? In that case I won't be able to store the child process's stdout to data. Boost's [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.io) also mentions the following

> [Warning] Warning
>   The pipe will cause a deadlock if you try to read after nm exited

Hence it seems that the check for c.running() should be there in the while loop.

How do I get the stdout (and stderr) from the processes that finish running before the program reaches the while loop?

Comment: Use async mode? And BTW the warning makes no sense, since the process can still exit between the check and the getline call.

Comment: How robust does your processing need to be?  The solution will be different for a short-lived shell utility that will write only a small amount of data that can be easily buffered compared to a long-lived child process that's going to write large amounts of data to both stdout and stderr.

Comment: @AndrewHenle This is going to be part of a utility that has to be very robust.

Comment: This is probably relevant, then:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207006/how-to-ensure-that-we-read-all-lines-from-boostchild-process  Note that saving the data the child process outputs to memory can be a problem if that child process writes a lot of data to stderr or stdout.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that whats the wait call is there for. The child process isn't actually gone in whatever OS before that (it merely changes state after it's not in running state).