# Timeout and System() function in C/C++

Tags: c++, shell

I'am trying to call a program within my C++ code using system() function.
Also I want to set an upper bound for runtime using Timeout.
When I combine both using

```
system(timeout 10s ./app_to_launch)
```

the host C++ code seems to wait for 10s without launching app_to_launch.
Can anyone help me understand what's happening ?
Thanks :)

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624004/running-a-process-using-boost-process-in-async-mode-with-timeout

Comment: Did you mean `system("timeout 10s ./app_to_launch")`?

Comment: Your interpretation of your observations of the program's behavior is unlikely to be correct.  And if indeed you get a ten-second delay then that strongly suggests that the C++ program is not (directly) the problem.  My crystal ball tells me that when launched under control of `timeout`, the app in question does nothing visible to you for at least ten seconds.

Comment: Yes I meant system("timeout 10s ./app_to_launch"). Also when I run the app in question using the same command but in a terminal it works.